# how to update one2many field in odoo wizard form to check data before report?

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo

I'm trying print report form wizard view, the report gets data from a method that returns a list of dictionaries, all I need to update an one2many field lines with the same data form the report method to display the data before press print,
this is the method

```
@api.multi
def product_summary(self,date_from, date_to):
    product_summary_dict = {}
    data = []
    if date_from and date_to:
        order_detail = self.env['pos.order'].search([('date_order', '>=',date_from),
                                                     ('date_order', '<=', date_to)])
        if order_detail:
            for each_order in order_detail:
                for each_order_line in each_order.lines:
                    if each_order_line.product_id.name in product_summary_dict:
                        product_qty = product_summary_dict[each_order_line.product_id.name]
                        product_qty += each_order_line.qty
                        total_sales = each_order_line.price_unit * product_qty
                        res1= {
                            "name": each_order_line.product_id.name,
                            "sold_qty": product_qty,
                            "price_unit": each_order_line.price_unit,
                            'total_sales': total_sales,
                        }
                        data.append(res1)
                    else:
                        product_qty = each_order_line.qty
                        total_sales = each_order_line.price_unit * product_qty
                    product_summary_dict[each_order_line.product_id.name] = product_qty;
                    res2 = {
                        "name": each_order_line.product_id.name,
                        "sold_qty": product_qty,
                        "price_unit": each_order_line.price_unit,
                        'total_sales': total_sales,
                    }
                    data.append(res2)
    if data:
        datas = list({v['name']: v for v in data}.values())
        print(len(datas))
        print(datas)
        return datas
    else:
        return {}
```

I need to update this field

```
invoice_line_ids = fields.One2many('acc.lines', 'req_ref', string='Bill Lines',
                                   copy=True)
```

which it gets its values from this model

```
class reportline(models.TransientModel):
_name = 'report.line'

name = fields.Char(string="", required=False, )
sold_qty = fields.Char(string="", required=False, )
price_unit = fields.Char(string="", required=False, )
total_sales = fields.Char(string="", required=False, )

report = fields.Many2one(comodel_name="pos.reports", string="", required=False, )
```

how to update the field form the method above

thanks in advance

Comment: Use the special [commands](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/odoo/models.py#L3435) format to manipulate the set of records stored in/associated with the field.

Comment: great but I can't use it in my code can you help me on it